# rails HABTM migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From a practical and best practices perspective, should rails models that have HABTM association also have a defined model for example `users_groups.rb`.  So, should you

```
script generate model ...
```

or simply

```
script generate migration ...
```

On one hand the join table is simply two fields and shouldn't have any methods of its own, on the other hand, in rails (model = table). So would it be wise to have it defined in models as well as in migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi as for me if you have `has_and_belongs_to_many` you don't need any model but if you use `has_many`+`:through` you'll need one